# Flutter Firebase random String

Tags: string, flutter, dictionary, random

Does anyone know how I can put the String _map before the _chars that there is then a map with a random String like this : AllComments.df8dfd or AllComments.erte84 :

```
AllComments

    df8dfd : "hello"
    erte84 : "cool"
```

```
static const _chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
 String _map = 'AllComments.';
  Random _rnd = Random();

  String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
      length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
```

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Because I want to display all the messages that a user wrote in a comment page :)

Comment: So why do you want a randomized string?

Comment: Because everytime when a user want to post a new comment

Comment: Or do you know how I can do a easy way to do a comment system? :)

Comment: Why not use the timestamp as the id? Or have firebase generate the id for you? This seems like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so maybe considering reworking this question to show your root problem rather than trying to get your potentially unideal attempt to work.